# Vue form doesn't submit using a PHP file when using the WHMCS local API

Tags: php, html, forms, whmcs

I'm trying to use the local WHMCS API as I have WHMCS stored under a sub-domain so both are on the same server.

I have the following form

```html
<FlashMessage message="Message sent!" />

<form action="./backend/contact.php" method="POST">
  <div class="mb-4">
    <label class="block" for="name">
      <span class="text-gray-900">Full name</span>
      <input
        class="form-input mt-1 block w-full outline-none"
        placeholder="Sherlock Holmes"
        required
        id="name"
        name="name"
        type="text"
      />
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="mb-4">
    <label class="block" for="email">
      <span class="text-gray-900">Email address</span>
      <input
        class="form-input mt-1 block w-full outline-none"
        placeholder="sherlock@bakerstreet.com"
        required
        id="email"
        name="email"
        type="email"
      />
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="mb-4">
    <label class="block" for="department">
      <span class="text-gray-700">Department</span>
      <select
        class="form-select mt-1 block w-full outline-none"
        id="department"
        name="department"
      >
        <option value="1">General Support</option>
        <option value="2">Hosting Support</option>
        <option value="3">Domain Support</option>
        <option value="4">Game Support</option>
      </select>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="mb-4">
    <label class="block" for="message">
      <span class="text-gray-900">Message</span>
      <textarea
        class="form-input mt-1 block w-full outline-none h-56 resize-none"
        placeholder="Enter your message here"
        required
        id="message"
        name="message"
        type="text"
      />
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="flex mt-6">
    <label class="flex items-center">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" />
      <span class="ml-2">
        I agree to the
        <a href="#" class="underline">privacy policy</a>
      </span>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="flex mt-6">
    <label class="flex items-center">
      <button
        type="submit"
        class="flex items-center py-3 px-6 border rounded bg-gray-800 hover:bg-gray-900 font-medium text-white transition duration-300 ease-in-out"
      >
        <i class="fas fa-paper-plane mr-4"></i>
        Send
      </button>
    </label>
  </div>
</form>

<script>
import FlashMessage from "../components/FlashMessage";

export default {
  name: "Contact",
  components: {
    FlashMessage
  },
  data() {
    return {
      showMsg: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onSubmit() {
      this.showMsg = true;
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.showMsg = false;
      }, 3000);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

and here is the contact.php file

```php
<?php
include("/home/hostedca/billing.hostedcarbon.com/includes/api.php");

$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$department = $_POST["department"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

$command = "OpenTicket";
$postData = array(
    "deptid" => "$department",
    "name" => "$name",
    "email" => "$email",
    "subject" => "Contact form Inquiry from $name for $department",
    "message" => "$message",
    "priority" => "Medium",
    "markdown" => false,
);

// Call the localAPI function
$results = localAPI($command, $postData);
if ($results['result'] == 'success') {
    echo 'Message sent successfully!';
} else {
    echo "An Error Occurred: " . $results['result'];
}
?>
```

Not sure if I need to add this code

```php
$api_identifier = "";
$api_secret = "";

$postfields = array(
    "identifier" => $api_identifier,
    "secret" => $api_secret,
    "action" => "OpenTicket",
    "responsetype" => "json",
);
```

The `include` PATH is the full cPanel path to the API file. However, when I submit the form I get a 404 nothing gets displayed errors included. Not sure if I need to use the external API as it's on a sub-domain but it's on the same server, any help or examples would be great because nothing is being echoed or printed on submit.

I have a flash message in place but I don't want to active it until the form is submitting correctly, just not sure if I need to add more to the `onSubmit` method.

[image]